# Перебор массива

Tags: алгоритм, php

есть на входе 3 массива в которых содержатся строки, пример массивов:

```
Array ( [0] => один [1] => два [2] => три )
Array ( [0] => четыре [1] => пять)
Array ( [0] => шесть [1] => семь [2] => восемь )
```

нужно перебрать все возможные варианты сложения элементов массивов и сложить это все в один массив, вот пример того что должно получиться, только это только часть, нужны все варианты

```
Array ( [0] => один [1] => два [2] => три [3] => четыре [4] => пять [5] => шесть [6] => семь [7] => восемь [8] => один два [8] => один три [9] => один четыре ... [n] => один три восемь ... и т.д )
```

P.S это все на php нужно сделать

P.P.S элементы не должны повторяться

Comment: Не понятно.

Comment: Варианты "один три" и "три один" нужны? Или один из них?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8;');
$arr1=Array('один', 'два', 'три');
$arr2=Array('четыре', 'пять');
$arr3=Array('шесть', 'семь', 'восемь');
$arr= array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
$size=sizeof($arr);
$res=Array();
for ($i=1; $i<pow(2, $size); $i++){
    $tmp='';        
    for($j=0; $j<$size; $j++){
        if (getBit($i, $j)==1) $tmp.=$arr[$j].' ';
    };
    if (sizeof(explode(' ', $tmp))<5) $res[]=$tmp; // ленивый костыль :)
};
echo implode("<BR/>\n", $res);

function getBit($value, $pos) {
    return (int) (($value^pow(2, $pos))-$value<0);
};
```

Comment: блин, забыл написать, что один элемент массива на выходе должно быть склеен не больше чем из 3 первоначальных элементов

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую реализовать свой вариант, пока мысль не пропала, а потом попробую ваш, и выберу что мне больше подойдет)

Comment: @ReinRaus - не пугайте вы так народ

    ($value^pow(2, $pos))-$value<0)?1:0 //  ^.^

Comment: @AlexWindHope,  
    
    echo (1==0); 
ничего не выводит, а нужен именно ноль, ведь getBit возвращает цифру в двоичной записи числа $value в позиции $pos

Comment: Ну так добавьте примведение типа, да я понял зачем вы так сделали, но это страшно =) 

     $integerVar = (int) $booleanVar;

Comment: .

    echo (int)(1==0);

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот решил эту задачу своим способом, все выполняется как мне нужно ;)

Гк наверное, но все же, кому не лень, дайте советы по оптимизации, буду благодарен)

P.S пугайтесь такого количества циклов :D

```
<?php   
$one = explode(', ', $_POST['name1']);
$two = explode(', ', $_POST['name2']);
$three = explode(', ', $_POST['name3']);

$count_one = count($one);
$count_two = count($two);
$count_three = count($three);

$result = '';

for($i = 0; $i < max($count_one, $count_two); $i++){
    $k = 0;
    while($k < $count_two){
        $result .= $one[$i].' '.$two[$k].', ';
        $k++;
    }
}
$result = explode(', ', $result);

$result2 = '';
for($i = 0; $i < max($count_three, count($result)); $i++){
    $k = 0;
    while($k < $count_three){
        $result2 .= $result[$i].' '.$three[$k].', ';
        $k++;
    }
}
$result2 = explode(', ', $result2);

$final = array_merge($one, $two, $three ,$result, $result2);

print_r($final);
?>
```

Comment: А если шесть чисел надо объединить? О_о Или вдруг концепция приложения изменится и придется данные из пяти массивов крутить-вертеть. Тогда всю логику целиком придется переделывать, в моем варианте нужно будет просто найти и заменить цифру **5** в первом случае, и добавить четвертый и пятый массив в array_merge_recursive во-втором случае.

Comment: ты прав, но приложение к счастью переделываться не будет)

Comment: Все так думают по началу ;D

Comment: Вообще все это довольно легко заврнуть в функцию с неопределенным количеством аргументов и не чудить такого Г, как `$one`, `$two`, `$N` =)